# Runtime Error : When using downloadstring(uri) in production

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-7

I use the following method to read server resource file to a string,

```
public string ReadFile(Uri uri)
{
  try
   {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            return client.DownloadString(uri);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      ExLog(ex);                 
    }
  }
```

This works well in Development and SIT environment(where URL can be http://localhost or http://(IP address)), but problem occurs in production environment where the URL is https://xxx-yyy.com

I get the following exception : The remote name could not be resolved : 'xxx-yyy.com'

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your server box have access to internet? Do you need to configure any proxies? Authentication?

Comment: Yes, it can be accessible via the internet.

Comment: I think what Rubens meant was; Does your server access the internet via a proxy? If so, you need to configure this in your web.config.

Comment: No I do not configure anything in the web.config for proxy.

Comment: Your error message suggest an DNS error, so I suppose your server isn't configured to access the internet. You should ask that to your server administrator.

Comment: Hi Rubens - Just to clarify, Do you mean my production server should have access to the internet?

Comment: the server has access to the internet.

Comment: If you remote into the box and navigate to the URL you are trying to visit, does it resolve in IE?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem with DNS lookup, and I was able to solve this issue by configuring server IP so my uri made up with IP.

I feel that there should be an ultimate solution for this issue.